# Empty sections cannot be broken, making page look stretched out

Tags: spacing, sectioning, page-breaking, paragraphs

This is almost duplicate to question [Random unwanted space between paragraphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36423/random-unwanted-space-between-paragraphs) but I don't even use `\par`.

I'm using `pdflatex` to compile a .tex file. As I wrote my text I noticed a sudden change in how the paragraphs of my document were spaced. From being just indented there appeared a huge gap between paragraphs. The only change between the two versions was a single word.

**Edit:** Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[openright]{scrbook}[2007/12/24]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}
Ipsum dolor et amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 

Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. ipsum dolor sit amet. Dor sit amet. 
Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

 Dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

 At vero eos et accusam et justo. Stet no sea ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 

At et et ea rebum. Stet clita, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   
 Clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor.

%\textbf{Test}

\section{Second}
\subsection{Second.1}
\section{Third}
\subsection{Third.1}
\section{Fourth}
\subsection{Fourth.1}
\end{document}
```

When the comment character in the line before \section{Second} is removed the weird spacing happens.

Images of the problem:

**Before**

[Correct paragraph spacing http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/8839/smallparagraphgap.jpg](http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/8839/smallparagraphgap.jpg)

**After**

[paragraph spacing too large http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/7645/largeparagraphgap.jpg](http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/7645/largeparagraphgap.jpg)

After inserting the word "Test" everything messed up. The paragraphs dropped way below their predecessors. I also noted that when the `\section{Second}` is changed to `\chapter{...}` the spacing is back to normal.
What is happening?

Comment: Unless someone has their crystal ball polished I suspect that the question is not answerable in this form. try to make a minimal complete document that shows the effect so we can reproduce. Just delete stuff until the problem goes away and post the smallest version with the problem. Usually by doing this you spot what is wrong and so don't need to ask, but if you do need to ask, it gives us a chance to answer.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I suspect you have a large unbreakable object at the bottom of the second page. By inserting one word, the paragraph spanning the page break gets one line longer, so the large object is moved to the next page. The "flushbottom" property of the book class results in the paragraphs getting dragged apart. Ok, let's see how good my crystal ball is ;-)

Comment: OMG you got an awesome crystal ball. I had a figure environment setting a label at the bottom of the page. When I commented those1 3 lines the paragraph spacing was back to normal. Thanks

Comment: Can you change your comment into an answer so I can mark this question as solved?

Comment: Will do, but as it stands the question should really be closed as too localized. It would be much more helpful to others if you could provide at least the LaTeX sources for this page. In principle, a `figure` environment should **not** produce this effect, as it can float somewhere else. So I suspect you're using the `[H]` option or something. With your source text, one could discuss alternatives which could help other users in the same situation.

Comment: Ok then the question should be closed (for now) since I cannot allow myself so much time to work up a MWE right now. As to the figure it's simply: \begin{figure} \label{Bla} \end[figure}. I guess there is some default space reserved for a figure which causes this behaviour.

Comment: @BandGap It's bad mojo to say "I don't have time" on forums where you are likely to ask questions :)

Comment: @recluze I can see that at the downvotes. But since the MWE would be procrastination right now it has to wait until I have more spare time.

Comment: @BandGap I can certainly understand (as can the other people here) but they take time out of _their_ busy schedule for us as well. So, even if we don't have time, the polite thing at the very least would be to not say that we're busy.

Comment: @recluze You are absolutely right. Considering your argument it's not procrastination making a MWE, so I did. :)

Comment: And with the MWE it's easy. A page break is absolutely forbidden directly after a section title, so the empty section titles are "glued" together. As soon as you start inserting text there, the problems will disappear. Maybe you can just write `todo` or something just to have *some* text.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Ok, thanks. But I still don't understand why the paragraph spacing is increased to fill the page. I guess the idea is to have an even grey value but wouldn't it be better to stick to one paragraph spacing throughout the document and have a larger white area at the bottom and the sections on the next page?

Comment: Well it's a simple design decision to force *flush bottom* formatting for the `book` class. You can get what you want by adding `\raggedbottom` to your preamble.

Comment: @StephanLehmke -- if "some text" or probably even `\leavevmode` is added after the first `\subsection`, the page break is moved down.  the reason is that `\subsection` requires something to continue in horizontal mode, and not finding it, never gets to an acceptable break point.  i'm sure david or egreg could explain it better, but a quick test will demonstrate the fix.  moral, always put some dummy text after a run-in (sub)section heading.  (i voted to reopen, but couldn't think of a good way to edit.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton You're right; the sequence of `\section` and `\subsection` commands has no break point, so the whole thing is taken to the next page. So the added example shows exactly that the first diagnosis was correct: a big undivisible chunk forces TeX to spread the page.

Comment: Thanks for reopening - I'll glue my comments together to an answer now :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A page break is absolutely forbidden directly after a section title, so the empty section titles are "glued" together.

Without the "Test", the block of section titles just fits on the page, after inserting "Test" it doesn't fit. As there is no breakpoint inbetween, the whole block of section titles goes to the next page:

[image]

The strange "stretching out" of paragraphs on the first page is caused by the fact that books are by default set *flush bottom*. That means, if there is any stretchability at all on the page, everything will be stretched such that the bottom of the content sits exactly on the bottom of the page.

You can get a different behaviour by adding the declaration `\raggedbottom` to the preamble of your document. This leads to:

[image]

*But beware! It is usually not desired that all pages in a book end on a different height!*

Anyway, the real "problem" is the empty body of the sections, which is surely not considered as a long-term situation. As soon as you start inserting text there, the problems will disappear. Maybe you can write "todo" there or something just to have some text.

Even if I just add `\leavevmode` I get this result (without `\raggedbottom`):

[image]

Here's the modified MWE:

```
\documentclass[openright]{scrbook}[2007/12/24]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}
Ipsum dolor et amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 

Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. ipsum dolor sit amet. Dor sit amet. 
Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

 Dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

 At vero eos et accusam et justo. Stet no sea ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 

At et et ea rebum. Stet clita, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   
 Clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor.

\textbf{Test}

\section{Second}
\leavevmode
\subsection{Second.1}
\leavevmode
\section{Third}
\leavevmode
\subsection{Third.1}
\leavevmode
\section{Fourth}
\leavevmode
\subsection{Fourth.1}
\leavevmode
\end{document}
```

Comment: And now we have something that is useful for everyone :)