# Gap between double-spaced paragraphs with table

Tags: tables, setspace

I have the code for a table between two blocks of texts (of multiple paragraphs). When the text is single-spaced, there is no problem; however, when I doublespace the text using `setspace` and singlespace the table, a longer gap is evident between the paragraphs where the code for the table is in the .tex file (the table is printed on the following page):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\begin{doublespace}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{singlespace}
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
Left        & Right\\
Hello       & Goodbye\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{singlespace}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{doublespace}
\end{document}
```

Below you can see the longer (slightly, though noticeable) gap preceding the "Lorem ipsum..." paragraph, which is where the code for the table is:

[image: You can see the longer gap before the start of the "Lorem ipsum..." paragraph.]

Comment: That is some stretch filling the page, so all pages end at the same place. You can try `\raggedbottom`. [Random unwanted space between paragraphs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36429)

Comment: The `singlespace` environment itself places some whitespace. Put the invironment inside the `table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment `singlespace` adds some whitespace. As does
`table` and `center`.

I suggest doing this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\begin{doublespace}
    \section{}
    \lipsum[1-2]

    \begin{table}[t]
        \singlespacing
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            Left        & Right\\
            Hello       & Goodbye\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \lipsum[1-2]

\end{doublespace}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Replacing `singlespace` with `singlespacing` seems to have done the trick without `raggedbottom`.

Comment: Jap, `\raggedbottom` was a leftover to realize that this isn't the cause. You can remove it.