# footmisc's bottom option and memoir's footnotes

Tags: spacing, footnotes, memoir, footmisc

In order to avoid overstretched inter-paragraph-glue I would like to use [`footmisc` with the `bottom` option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36429/59023). However it interferes  with my footnote setup. See the following example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{\leftmargin}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1\hfill}
\begin{document}
Some text \footnote{Here I have a footnote that's long enough to break 
over a line, just a little bit longer still.}
\end{document}
```

This is how my footnotes are supposed to look like:

[image: Without footmisc]

This is how they look after loading footmisc:

[image]

I understand that `footmisc` also has a `hang` option which formats footnotes roughly as in the first example, however I'd prefer to use `memoir`'s footnotes and use `footmisc` just to keep all the extra vertical whitespace between footnotes and running text. How do I stop `footmisc` from interfering with anything else than that? Or is there a better way of achieving the same thing?

Comment: As soon as you use `footmisc` you overwrite the `memoir` features (AFAIR), so you cannot use both. Have you read the `memoir` manual. The bottom feature from `footmisc` has recently been added to `memoir`, see `\feetatbottom`

Comment: @daleif I had not seen that yet. So the default in a `twoside` document with `memoir` is `\flushbottom`, but `\feetatbottom` is to be used together with `\raggedbottom`,  so I would have to switch to that first, and `\feetatbottom` would then avoid `\raggedbottom`'s inconsistent text block size problem?

Comment: What do you mean by inconsistent text block size? They do not have the same size because they are not fully filled in which is what you allow when you use ragged bottom. Feet at bottom can be used when your document does not use flush bottom.