# Leaving a blank line leads to a huge skip

Tags: spacing

in my LaTeX report, I would like to separate paragraphs by a small vertical blank space. I'm doing that by typing

```
End of the old paragraph. \newline

New paragraph goes here.
```

This worked well for most of the cases. However, there is one particular chapter where this procedure produces extremely large vertical blank spaces.

The chapter looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
% Figure with subfigures
\end{figure}

First paragraph. \newline

Second paragraph. \newline

Third paragraph. \newline

Fourth paragraph.
```

However, this results in rediculously large blank spaces. How can I fix this?
I have the feeling that this is not the best approach to divide paragraphs. What is the "optimum" way to do it? I do not want a space at the beginning of a paragraph.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Since the currently given answers do not work for you and seem to work differently, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Don't use `\newline` at the and of a paragraph. This leads to an extra empty line at the end of the paragraph and the warning `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines ...` If you want space between paragraphs then use the `parskip` package (or if you're using a KOMA-Script class the `parskip` option).

Comment: the `\newline` commands are completely wrong in that position, just add `\usepackage{parskip}` to set `\parskip` to some none zero value.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check out the `parskip` package!

Comment: related/duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36423/

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to manually typeout the `\newline` command. LaTeX and TeX related systems automatically consider a blank line as an end of a paragraph. you have extra space because you force a line break and then also break a paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
First paragraph. 

Second paragraph. 

Third paragraph. 

Fourth paragraph.
\end{document}
```

gives out:

[image]

The effect is more apparent with some lines of text

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
First paragraph. First paragraph. First paragraph. First paragraph. First paragraph. First paragraph. First paragraph. First paragraph. 

Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. 

Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. 

Fourth paragraph.
\end{document}
```

You could also manually specify an extra skip to be inserted (suitable for occasional spacings, not systematic), with `smallskip` `medskip` or `bigskip` ie

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
First paragraph. \medskip

Second paragraph. \smallskip

Third paragraph. \bigskip

Fourth paragraph.
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Also, as Steven B. Segletes suggests, you could define, in your preamble, the parskip to be a specific amount,ie `\parskip=1ex\relax`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However, omitting the `\newline` makes the blank space even bigger (at least visually).

Comment: @DmitriiC. You then have to create a minimal working example from `documentclass` to `end{document}` to replicate the problem

Comment: I've tried to, but I'm not able to reproduce the problem. However... I have absolutely no clue why, but putting`\raggedbottom` in front of the problematic chapter did the trick...

Comment: Don't forget the specification on a nonzero `\parskip=1ex\relax`, for example, to accomplish the goal, as well.