# How to ensure that margins are correct - geometry package is not working properly

Tags: margins

I must prepare my thesis to meet following criteria:

- A4 paper,
- all margins must be equal to 2,5 cm,
- font must be Times New Roman, 12 points,
- page numbering on the bottom of the page, in the middle

I used `geometry` package (line: `\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}`) to set properly margins. 
Unfortunately, publishing house requested to amend top and bottom margins, because they're too small. I used screen ruler application and I can confirm that something is wrong. Could you suggest solution? I tried to change order of loading packages, but it doesn't help.

My minimal working example is as follows:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{mwbk} % polish counterpart of book class

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \usepackage{blindtext} % package for generating some dummy text
    \usepackage{apalike}
        \let\bibhang\relax
    \usepackage[round]{natbib}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
    \usepackage{floatrow}
        \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
        \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=bottom}

    \usepackage{polski}
     \usepackage[english, polish]{babel} 
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[unicode, naturalnames, breaklinks]{hyperref}
        \def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}

    \usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
        \graphicspath{ {grafika/} {ObrazkiZRaportuZDyzagregacji/figures/} }

    \raggedbottom % Solution from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36423/random-unwanted-space-between-paragraphs

    \usepackage[all]{nowidow}

    \usepackage[lang=english]{bicaption}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% THERE's an issue

    % MARGINS must be equal 2,5 cm
    \usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

    % MUST be Times
    \usepackage{times}
    \usepackage{mathptmx} 
        \urlstyle{same} 

    \linespread{1.3}

    \usepackage{fancyhdr}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

 \pagestyle{fancy}
    \lhead{}
    \rhead{}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark }
    \fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
    \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}

\blindtext[10]

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.7]{universe.jpg}
\bicaption{Kosmos}{The Universe}
\label{fig:univerise}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}
``I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe'' \citep{adams1995hitchhiker}


\bibliographystyle{papalike}
    \twocolumn
    {\footnotesize \bibliography{references}}
\end{document}
```

and the result PDF (I run 'Screen Ruler' app to show margins):

[image: top margins incorrect]

and bottom margins seems to be too small - let me cite publishing house: "Margins - bottom margins are a little too small (it is 1 cm, should be 2.5 cm)"

[image: bottom margins is too small]

Comment: So you mean the head and foot should be within the vertical margins (not the usual understanding of margins in terms of geometry)?

Comment: Try `includehead` and `includefoot`.

Comment: Add the option `includeheadfoot` to `geometry`. By default the margins are relative to the main body. And since all margins are equal, you can shorten the option to a simple `margin=2.5cm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you want the header and footer included within the text body you have to use either `includehead` and `includefoot` or `includeheadfoot` as options for geometry.

[image: headinclude]

Btw: Your document does not compile without disabling caption's compatibility mode.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{compatibility=false}{caption}
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{mwbk} % polish counterpart of book class

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \usepackage{blindtext} % package for generating some dummy text
    \usepackage{apalike}
        \let\bibhang\relax
    \usepackage[round]{natbib}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
    \usepackage{floatrow}
        \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
        \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=bottom}

    \usepackage{polski}
     \usepackage[english, polish]{babel} 
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[unicode, naturalnames, breaklinks]{hyperref}
        \def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}

    \usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

    \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

    \raggedbottom % Solution from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36423/random-unwanted-space-between-paragraphs

    \usepackage[all]{nowidow}

    \usepackage[lang=english]{bicaption}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% THERE's an issue

    % MARGINS must be equal 2,5 cm
    \usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}

    % MUST be Times
    \usepackage{times}
    \usepackage{mathptmx} 
        \urlstyle{same} 

    \linespread{1.3}

    \usepackage{fancyhdr}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

 \pagestyle{fancy}
    \lhead{}
    \rhead{}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark }
    \fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
    \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}

\blindtext[10]

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.7]{universe.jpg}
\bicaption{Kosmos}{The Universe}
\label{fig:univerise}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}
``I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe'' \citep{adams1995hitchhiker}


\bibliographystyle{papalike}
    \twocolumn
    {\footnotesize \bibliography{references}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding 'disabling caption's compatibility mode' ---> I am using bicaption, I do not load caption package at all, because it is managed by bicaption. I am aware that there's a warning (caused by using mwbk class instead of book with bicaption), but it compile (at least on my computer and on the ShareLaTeX).

Comment: @matandked For me on TL17 it raised an error. But that was just an annotation. Important is the rest of the answer.