# Equations and equations tags in margins of koma script

Tags: equations, margins, koma-script, layout

I have a customized layout where there's a wide margin, sort of a 1.5 column document. I'd like to have the equations and equations tags in the margins, similar to what others do with `cuted` for a two-column document. I'd like to use both margins as in the pic below:

[image: MWE]

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[includemp, showframe,
            paperwidth=18.90cm,
            paperheight=24.58cm,
            top=2.170cm,
            bottom=3.510cm,
            inner=1.5835cm,
            outer=1.5835cm,
            marginparwidth=4.28cm,
            marginparsep=0.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

A short equation:

\begin{equation}
    A + B = C
\end{equation}

A long equation:

\begin{equation}
\sin x + \cos x + \tan x + \sinh x + \cosh x + \tanh x + \int \sin x dx + \int \cos x dx + \int \tan x dx + \sec x 
\end{equation}

\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
Another  short equation
\begin{equation}
    D + E = F
\end{equation}

Long equation again:
\begin{equation}
\sin x + \cos x + \tan x + \sinh x + \cosh x + \tanh x + \int \sin x dx + \int \cos x dx + \int \tan x dx + \sec x 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your sketch I assume that you only want long equations to go into the margins. You can easily widen the line at the appropriate equations using `changepage`'s `adjustwidth`. Note that you have to shift your equation up by one line if it is the first thing in the environment, as it is a list environment internally.

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[includemp, showframe,
            paperwidth=18.90cm,
            paperheight=24.58cm,
            top=2.170cm,
            bottom=3.510cm,
            inner=1.5835cm,
            outer=1.5835cm,
            marginparwidth=4.28cm,
            marginparsep=0.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\newenvironment{fullwidth}
  {\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax}}
  {\end{adjustwidth*}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

A short equation:

\begin{equation}
    A + B = C
\end{equation}

A long equation:

\begin{fullwidth}
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
  \begin{equation}
    \sin x + \cos x + \tan x + \sinh x + \cosh x + \tanh x + \int \sin x dx + \int \cos x dx + \int \tan x dx + \sec x 
  \end{equation}
\end{fullwidth}

\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
Another  short equation
\begin{equation}
    D + E = F
\end{equation}

Long equation again:
\begin{fullwidth}
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
  \begin{equation}
    \sin x + \cos x + \tan x + \sinh x + \cosh x + \tanh x + \int \sin x dx + \int \cos x dx + \int \tan x dx + \sec x 
  \end{equation}
\end{fullwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

---

If you want all equations to use the full width, you can also patch the `equation` environment by adding this to the preamble of your MWE:

```latex
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\newenvironment{fullwidth}
  {\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax}}
  {\end{adjustwidth*}}
\AddToHook{env/equation/before}{\begin{fullwidth}\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
\AddToHook{env/equation/after}{\end{fullwidth}}
```

Comment: Nice! Is there something we can do about the vertical space above the equation?

Comment: The `fullwidth` environment (incorrectly) terminates the current paragraph…

Comment: @Jollywatt Does it? How do you mean?

Comment: @RichardCosta Sorry, somehow missed your comment until now. I changed my answer to take care of that vertical space.

Comment: @schtandard You’re updated answer seems to work well! Except if there’s inter-paragraph vertical space, either due to TeX's “stretching” (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36423/105570)) or nonzero `\parskip`...
Is there a way to compensate for any extra vertical space that TeX might insert?

Comment: @Jollywatt I'm not entirely sure what you mean. The vertical space around `adjustwidth*` is governed by the usual dimensions for list environments, see [this anser](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300512/48973). You can adjust them to your liking. If this isn't what you mean, please ask a new question with an MWE showing what you need.