# Is there a convenient hook to patch all of the AMS display math environments?

Tags: amsmath, environments, patching

If I want to patch all of the `amsmath` display math environments to be wrapped in another environment (like for `equation` in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/546347/48973) to adjust the line width), is there a convenient way to patch all of these environments at once? That is, is there any common hook in these environments which can be used for this purpose? Or do I have to patch all of them individually?

In the following MWE, I have only patched `equation`, but want all of the others to be patched in the same way.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  showframe,
  includemp,
  margin=2cm,
  marginparwidth=5cm,
  marginparsep=.5cm,
  ]{geometry} % I know, terrible. It's just for illustration!
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\newenvironment{fullwidth}
  {\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax}}
  {\end{adjustwidth*}}
\preto\equation{\fullwidth}
\appto\endequation{\endfullwidth}

\begin{document}

\def\longeq{\sum_{i=1}^{20} i = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 + 15 + 16 + 17 + 18 + 19 + 20}
\def\alongeq{\sum_{i=1}^{20} i &= 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 + 15 + 16 + 17 + 18 + 19 + 20}

\begin{equation}
  \longeq
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}
  \longeq
\end{equation*}

\begin{multline}
  \longeq
\end{multline}

\begin{multline*}
  \longeq
\end{multline*}

\begin{gather}
  \longeq
\end{gather}

\begin{gather*}
  \longeq
\end{gather*}

\begin{align}
  \alongeq
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
  \alongeq
\end{align*}

\begin{flalign}
  \alongeq
\end{flalign}

\begin{flalign*}
  \alongeq
\end{flalign*}

\begin{alignat}{1}
  \alongeq
\end{alignat}

\begin{alignat*}{1}
  \alongeq
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: don't you just want to set `\displaywidth` do you need to patch at all?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Will that work? Just setting `\displaywidth` in my MWE didn't do anything. Will that always expand into the right margin in two-sided documents? More to the point though, this is more of an academic question for me. If I chose a bad example, just imagine that instead of just changing the width I want to also draw a border of alternating color around the equations or something like that.

Comment: It could be made to work:-) otherwise patching `\start@align` and `\endalign` will do `align`, `align*`, `flalign`, `flalign*` then `\start@gather` and ...

Comment: using adjustwidth will affect the vertical space as well, looking at the code (as it  is a list enviornment)