# Why is the space between paragraphs different even though the code is exactly the same?

Tags: spacing

I have this issue that the space between paragraphs is sometimes of different size, even though I use exactly the same code specifications to write a new paragraph.

Does that have to do something with the specific content of the paragraph (i.e. starting with a citation)? It just looks aesthetically off when I am proofreading my text in pdf.

[image]

Comment: How should we know, if we do not know the code? Please always add a minimal working example, that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random unwanted space between paragraphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36423/random-unwanted-space-between-paragraphs)

Comment: And yes, it could also have to do something with the content, i.e., if you use large objects like figures, tables, boxes etc. and don't allow them to float.